# Subring of $R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Im having trouble with an exercise. Am I missing some information on the ring $R$?

Let $R$ be a ring. Which of the following are subrings of $R[X]$

Polynomials of degree less than $5$

Polynomials in which the odd powers of $X$ have coefficient $0$

Polynomials in which the even powers of $X$ have coefficient $0$

Comment: You are missing the subring criterion. Are those sets closed under the ring operations? Can you get a polynomial of degree $>5$ with operations on lower degree polynomials? Can you get polynomials with even degree terms as a result of a calculation involving odd degree polynomials? Can you get polynomials with odd degree terms as a result of a calculation involving even degree polynomials?

Comment: No, you are not missing any information about the ring $R$ to answer these (assuming that $R$ is unital).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft "(assuming that $R$ is unital)" is information we are missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $x^5 \cdot x^4=x^9$ you have shown that the polynomials of degree less than $5$ do not form a subring. Also for the even powers with coefficient $0$ a similar counterexample is $x^3 \cdot x^3=x^6$; check by yourself if the other set is a subring!